# explanation of SQL Server stored procedure / query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I was hoping someone could explain this snippet of a SQL Server 2005 stored procedure its part of a select query - I am competent in php mysql but ASP / SQL Server is not my forte!

```
+RTRIM(ISNULL(r.country,''))+'|'
+RTRIM(ISNULL(r.phone,''))+'|'
+RTRIM(ISNULL(r.fax,''))+'|'
+dbo.UKBN(RTRIM(ISNULL(r.bn,'')))+'|'
+RTRIM(ISNULL(r.bn,''))+'|'
+RTRIM(ISNULL(CAST (r.eventid AS varchar(5)),''))
)
```

I understand it takes db vars resets them if they are null to '' and trims them, then concatenates them together pipe separated.

This is the bit I don't get

```
+dbo.UKBN(RTRIM(ISNULL(r.bn,'')))+'|'
```

It seems to check if r.bn is null then resets to '' if so, then performs a trim, but then I do not understand what dbo.UKBN is / does????

It does not seem to be a table / var or another stored procedure - can someone explain what it is likely to be / do in this layout.

Comment: Stored procedure no, UDF (User Defined Function) maybe? Because surely it isn't a known MSSQL function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dbo.UKIPBN` is a scalar user defined function. In Management Studio look under `Programmability -> Functions -> Scalar-Valued Functions` to find it.

Comment: Thanks was exactly right and in right location - answered in under 2mins!

Answer (score 2):

`dbo.UKIPBN` is a user defined function. And it is scalar valued function. Try `Programmability -> Functions -> Scalar-Valued Functions` to find it.

Answer (score 1):

`dbo.UKBN` would be a [User-defined Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189593.aspx)